# NodeJS library with file query features

Tags: file, node.js

I'm searching for a library that has a query feature. So lets say I want to get all the JS files in a certain directory in a project. I could do something like

```
filesystem.query({
    paths:[{
        path:"c:/path/to/dir",
        recursive:true
    }],
    types:[".js"],
    excludes:["test.js"]
},successFn,failFn);
```

Does any library have this feature?

Comment: What modules did you investigate?

Comment: I've mostly looked at the the FS module http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Check out https://npmjs.org/, which might lead you towards [readdirp](https://github.com/thlorenz/readdirp) or [tromp](https://github.com/shanewholloway/node-tromp) or [fs2](https://github.com/medikoo/fs2)...

Comment: Those are looking promising `readdirp({ root: path.join(__dirname), fileFilter: '*.js' });` Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few modules with those kind of filtering possibilities:

- [readdirp](https://github.com/thlorenz/readdirp)
- [tromp](https://github.com/shanewholloway/node-tromp)
- [fs2](https://github.com/medikoo/fs2)

Answer (score 3):

Using [fs.readdir](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback)

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('.', function (error, files)
{
    files.filter(function (fileName)
    {
        return /.*.js$/.test(fileName);
    }).forEach(yourfunc);
});
```

Using  [glob](https://npmjs.org/package/glob)

```
require("glob").glob("*.js", function (er, files) { ... });
```